# Experience Learning in the Mir Yeshiva

Tags: yeshiva-school, mir

Is anyone on this platform a Talmid or Alumnus of the Mir Yeshiva in Jerusalem (and learns/learned under R'Asher Arieli)? If so, I have a few questions:

1. It seems very much like there is no structure there- I'm coming from a yeshiva where everyone has a designated Makom where he Davens, learns, and stores a few of his seforim, is this possible in the Mir?
2. Regarding R' Asher Arieli's shiur- if you can give me some info on what the style is and on what level of Yiddish you need to be at for solid comprehension of the shiur?
3. I am currently in an online college that I cannot take off from, is it possible to kind of be under the radar spending maybe like 6 hours a week doing online college from a dira?
4. What are some common mistakes that people make during their time in the Mir that if avoided could have given them a much better and fulfilling experience there, and how could such mistakes be avoided?

Comment: 1 and 3 aren't opinion based. Maybe even 2.

Comment: Regarding 3: Make sure you are following their rules. If is not fair to the yeshiva to go there intending to not follow their rules. Or look for a different place to go. Many yeshivas will let you do college.

Comment: In your situation I would strongly not advise doing what you suggest because Reb OA's shiur is very high speed and incomprehensible enough to people learning full time, let alone if you have other commitments. In other words, you won't learn how to learn by going to a very fast shiur, which is *kimat* not aiming to help you do that. Try a smaller yeshiva, e.g. Toras Simcha.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE he only needs 6 hours a week though. That's just an hour a day, and can spend 12 hours on Rav Asher every day.

Comment: It's _so_ crowded. My son liked it there, but I couldn't deal with the crowding when I visited him. YMMV of course.

Comment: @robev Mind space.

Answer (score 4):

Didn't learn specifically in his shiur but:

1 - People have a set place to learn/set place to sit in shiur, but new people might have to fight for a spot.

2 - From what I've heard it's pretty basic Yiddish. He taught himself Yiddish to give the shiur. I know people who knew no Yiddish and picked it up after a month of working on it intensely.

3 - Officially you're not supposed to have internet devices in your dira, but you'll take a survey to see how many people follow that. People openly go to internet cafes though in the neighbourhood.

4 - This is probably appropriate for its own question. Probably similar answers to other yeshivos. Nothing unique to Mir comes to mind other than the vast size of the place makes it easy to get lost without hadracha from a Rebbe and a consistent, good group of peers.

Comment: 1- Good chance you won't get a seat and may even need to watch him on the screen outside the room. 2- Yiddish can be very hard to learn for some people, and a month to be able to understand a shiur sounds extremely quick to me. 3- You will definitely be looked down upon by many guys if they know you have an internet device. 4- I agree 100%. I would just add that if you don't have friends in the Yeshivah and some in other yeshivos too, it will be very difficult for you for many reasons. Disclaimer: I was never in the Mir but just saying what I heard.

Comment: @AYALTAAROG Only 20% of what he is saying is Yiddish. The rest is Hebrew or Aramaic as he's quoting the gemarra, or using Yeshivish like chiluk or diyuk etc. and the Yiddish he is using is basically connector words (if so, what if, how come, etc.)

Comment: You're under-representing the amount of Yiddish.

Comment: How do you know if you've never been in the shiur?

Comment: Because it's a Yiddish Shiur, and I know what it means to be a yiddish shiur.